# can we say "Don't run. Be careful, you may trip over the stone slabs"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

Some gardens often have some large thick flat pieces of stone for decoration or easy walk as shown in the above picture.

In everyday conversation, can we say "**Don't run. Be careful, you may trip over the stone slabs**" or "**Don't run. Be careful, you may trip over the stones**"?

Comment: It is indeed a stone slab; you might also call it a 'paving stone'.

Comment: Note, you'd probably use "might" rather than "may" there.